# Does the H1, body and other content created during 301 redirect is important?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Every website has few to many 301 redirects. But I have seen the differences in the content while 301 redirect is issued. For example, on one of my site when I make a redirect using .htaccess, I get his message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.example.com/text-permalink-of-the-site/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at www.example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

However, when I use a plugin, though I get the same status, that is 301 Moved Permanently, but the body content is entirely different. In this case I get whole 404 page where the title is also showing that the page is not found but actually the 301 header status is sent. In this case the plugin doesn't use any .htaccess or rewrite rule but uses a script and/or database, I think.

So, my main question is whether the body content is important while generating a 301 redirect?? And how Google looks them??

Comment: I wouldn't think it's important at all. As far as I know, once you send a 301 in the header most crawlers will just move on to the next page and ignore anything on the '301 page'.

Comment: In fact I changed the permalink structure on one of my site recently. And I have to apply 301 redirects to about 800 posts. One way is to use .htaccess and create one-to-one redirects. But I have read somewhere that it may cause some problems because every URL will have to go through all 800 redirects and then show in the browser. So I was thinking to use a plugin to handle all these 301 redirect.